# Passing a value from input in table onto controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a code in my view :

```html
<tr>
<td><input name ="webname" id="webname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""></td>
<td><input name ="webadd" id="webadd" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""></td>
<td><input name ="notes" id="notes" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""></td>
</tr>
```

and then i have my controller code right here :

```html
public function submiturl ()
    {   
       DB::insert('insert into urllinks (website_name, website_address, notes) values (?, ?, ?)', [#,#,#]);         
    }
```

i want to pass value on view into controller so that i can pass it into database as input (on #). what should i do?

Comment: please go and start with plenty tutorials .

Comment: can you reccomend me any keyword, i'm very confuse now

Comment: google it #  crud operation in laravel 5.4

Comment: please watch out these tutorials [Laravel 5.4](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017)

Comment: thanks all, i'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to create a form that posts to the route that leads to your controller

```
<form action='{{ url('route/here')}} method='post'> {{ csrf_field()}} 

<tr> <td><input name ="webname" id="webname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""></td> <td><input name ="webadd" id="webadd" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""></td> <td><input name ="notes" id="notes" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""></td> </tr> </form>
```

Then your routes file

```
Route::post('route-here', 'controllernamehere@submiturl');
```

Then your controller

```
$value = request('webadd');
$value2 = request('notes');
```

I would recommend using Laravel models to save data to the database.

Comment: i've try it, but i keep getting error message POST 500 (Internal Server Error), any ideas?

Comment: What does your Laravel. Lo

Comment: What does the Laravel.log say.

Comment: it says :
Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'website_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into urllinks (website_name, website_address, notes) values (, , ))' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cppa\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:647

Comment: That means you have created a column website_name which is not set to any value in your insert. Either insert a value into website_name when you do your insert or make that column nullable()

Comment: so it means the variable on form input didnt pass into controller right?

Comment: sorry i'm new in html php and laravel

Comment: Ok great. No problem that's what stack is for.

Answer (score 0):

If your form submit points to thet method, your submit() should receive the Request

```
public function submiturl( Request $request )
```

And then use the regular access to the input

`$request->all()`  will give you an array with all the form values.

```
$request->input('website_name')
```

will return the individual input's value.

Answer (score 0):

To submit the form in laravel

1. Create a form and add the csrf_field in the form

```html
<form action="/submit" method="POST">
    <input name ="webname" id="webname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    <input name ="webadd" id="webadd" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    <input name ="notes" id="notes" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>
```

2. Add a route in in the web.php file (for Laravel 5.4 or newer) or routes.php file (for older laravel versions)

   **Route::post('/submit', ['uses' => 'MyController@submit']);**
3. Create a controller using

   php artisan make:controller MyController
4. Create a function submit() in MyController

```html
public function submit(Request $request){
    
//you can get all request by using
$request->all();
        
//and you can access individual form item by
$request->website_name
//and perform your operations
}
```

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/) is a great place to start.
Also checkout [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)

Answer (score -1):

you should use jquery to post value asyncronous to controller if you not want to load a page, if yes, you can a